# Properties of the minimum of several random variables

Tags: random-variable, extreme-value

I've come across an interesting problem in my research that I don't quite know the answer to. Suppose I have a bunch of random variables:

$$ X_1, X_2, X_3, ... X_N $$

They are not identical but they are independently distributed. As a rule, they have different distributions. I am interested in the quantity:

$$ Z_N = \text{min}(X_1, ... X_N) $$

My first question: What can I say, in general, about the properties of $Z_N$? (Such as its expected value and variance) I understand that if the variables are IID, I can use [Extreme Value Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theory), but what if the variables have arbitrary distributions (say, different Gaussians?)

My second question: if all I have are *samples* of $X_i$, and not their distributions, and I get them one at a time online, is it possible to compute $E[Z_N]$ and $\text{Var}(Z_N)$ *without storing all the samples*?

Comment: The second question has a simple, satisfactory answer: from the online sequence of $(X_{1i}, \ldots, X_{Ni})$ you can construct the sequence of associated $Z_{i}$. Its sample moments can each be computed with $O(1)$ storage because all you have to do is accumulate the contributions from each observation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$P\{Z_n > \alpha\} = P\{X_1 > \alpha, X_2 > \alpha, \cdots, X_n > \alpha\}
= \prod_{i=1}^n P\{X_i > \alpha\}$$
and so
$$F_{Z_n}(\alpha\} = 1-P\{Z_n > \alpha\} = 1 - \prod_{i=1}^n \left(1- F_{X_i}(\alpha)\right).$$
For the special case when the $X_i$ are *exponential* random variables
with parameter $\lambda_i$ (and so $P\{X_i > \alpha\} = e^{-\lambda_i \alpha}$),
we easily get that $Z_n$ is an exponential random variable with parameter
$\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i$.

More generally, taking the derivative of $F_{Z_n}(\alpha\}$ with respect to
$\alpha$ via the product rule, we get the *density* $f_{Z_n}(\alpha)$ as
$$f_{Z_n}(\alpha) = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\alpha}F_{Z_n}(\alpha) = 
\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\prod_{j=1, j\neq i}^n \left(1- F_{X_j}(\alpha)\right)\right)f_{X_i}(\alpha)$$
which might at first glance *seem* to be a *mixture* of the $X_i$ 
densities, but really isn't
because the "weights" of the various densities are also functions of
$\alpha$ instead of being constants not depending on $\alpha$ and summing to $1$.

Comment: If I'm following you, you're computing the CDF to infer the PDF, using an (elegant) property of the CDF and the independence of each X_i. That's very useful. I will have to think on this a bit to see if it answers my other questions. Thanks!